# Writing an application for a part-time job

Tags: interviewing, applications, part-time

I'm looking for a part-time job at an international business from a specific country. I want to work as a software developer.

My plans are to work part-time until probably September (I still don't know if I'll be able to work full-time by then). Approximately within a year I'll go to that country to work and get a degree. As you may have guessed, my goal is to have my job position moved there, so I ensure a job once I go there.

My question is, how should I write my application so it catches recruiter's attention? Should I mention my plans? Should I write in Spanish or in English? And if I get an interview, what kind of questions should I expect?

Comment: (or I misunderstood your answers). My goal is to get hired in my country by a business from my destination country, not to get a job there from my country. Then, when I move in that country I'll still work for that business.

Comment: Oops, my previous comment should have "I think you misunderstood my question" before the actual text. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to explore and research about the employer before you start to write your application. So when you have a list of "must"s and "nice to have"s collected it would be easier to write more specific application.

- You must accompany your application with a cover letter and resume.
- Draft a resume with your skill set, work experience, education and a brief career objective. Then improve on this to make it more aligned to the employers requirement.
- In the cover letter, you must mention and highlight the skills and experience  most relevant to the original job description.
- You should always write the application in the language same as the job posting. But remember to mention your knowledge and proficiency level of other languages spoken in that country.
- You can briefly discuss your ambitions and explain how is it aligned to the employer's objective.
- Don't forget to highlight any proof you might have to show your work / experience / achievements. e.g. Links to any published paper, winning of any contest in a field related to the job, scores of internationally recognized language tests.
- If you have gained your educational degree from a premier institute then you can flaunt your institute's name.
- Mention of a valid visa and university acceptance would also be useful.
- The format and preferred style of writing a resume can be different in a country. It would be beneficial to research about that.
- Now, an important section is references. If you can provide any local references that would be a great boost to your chances of getting shortlisted.

You need to be patient and work on your application a few times before finalizing it. Make a draft and try to improve on it. When you are satisfied get it reviewed by a few people.

Hope that helped. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan demonstrates ambition and planning; good job on figuring out what you want.

However, it also depends on a lot of externalities going right. The desired company has to want to hire you in your home country, they have to want to move you to desired country (may be complicated / long shot for part time hire), you have to get accepted at desired college, visas need to happen, they have to want you to continue to work for them part time in desired country, and they have to want you to transition to full time. None of those are things you have a lot of control over.

So, start with the things you can control. Apply for work in your home country, and put your based foot forward according to your local hiring customs. Try to impress local recruiter before you worry about impressing international recruiter. If your English skills would be a plus in your home country, then use them. Otherwise, don't worry about it. You can deploy them in applications for transfer to other country.

Comment: So I should get a part-time job regardless of the connections of the business with my destionation country, am I right? And how can I ensure a job on that country?